# If-Then Constraint: If X < 4 Then T = 4 -X

Tags: integer-programming

All the generic If-then constraints do not seem to be gaining me any insight into this. I would like to form a mixed-integer program with Lingo which can minimize cost given that a series of:

- When $X < 4$ Then $T \ge 1$ & $Y = 1$
- Otherwise, when $x > 4$, $T = 0$ & $Y = 0$.

This is a network problem to transport solid waste. If there is waste transported then there is a fixed cost plus a cost per unit.

Comment: Post more context, please. It is quiet possible, that your condition can be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want
$$ x < 4 \rightarrow T \geq 1, y = 1$$
$$ x \geq 4 \rightarrow T = 0, y = 0$$

So, lets first address $y$:
$$ y \geq \frac{4-x}{M}$$
$$ y \leq 1+\frac{4-x}{M}$$
 where $M$ is a large constant. So if $x=0$, then you get $y \geq \epsilon, y \leq 1+\epsilon$ so $y=1$. If $x=5$ then you get $y \geq -\epsilon$ and $y \leq 1-\epsilon$ so $y=0$

As for $T$

$$ T \geq y $$
$$ T \leq My$$

should do it. If $y=0$, $0\leq T \leq M*0=0$. If $y=1$,$0\leq T \leq M$.

The quality of the LP relaxation of the MILP formulation is probably going to be very weak. You need some sort of bound on $x$ and $T$ to make this work, but you almost surely do in any real problem. The smaller you can make $M$ the better for both numerical stability and solve time.

Comment: I did not articulate the constraints clearly. I edited it to be more clear. Thank you, I am starting to understand the ability of the big M constraint.

Comment: Ok, reorganized my answer, actually makes it simpler

Comment: Much appreciation! Tis a great help.